# Spring boot RestController always get 404 Error code (GET Http request works well but all others result to the error code)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application with mongoDB as DB. Only GET Http Requests are working. For all other methods i get the Error code 404 (message not available)

The Application look like this:

```
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ManagementApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ManagementApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
 @RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<User> findAll() {
        LOGGER.info("Finding all User entries");
        return userService.findAllUsers();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public User findById(@PathVariable(value = "userId") String userId) {
        LOGGER.info("Getting the user with the id: " + userId);
        return userService.findUserWithId(userId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{userId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable(value = "userId") String userId) {
        LOGGER.info("Deleting the user with the id: " + userId);
        userService.deleteUser(userId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public User create(@RequestBody @Valid User user, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Creating or Updating a user with the following informations: " + user);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            throw new Exception("Error in request");
        }
        return userService.createOrUpdateUser(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public User update(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
        LOGGER.info("Updating the user with the following informations: " + user);
        return userService.createOrUpdateUser(user);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public void handleUserNotFound(Exception exception) {
        LOGGER.info("An Exception occured in controller " + exception.getMessage());
    }
```

For any rest call other than GET i get the following response:

```
"timestamp": "1475149066750",
  "status": "404",
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/user"
```

Please can anyone Help me on this ???

Comment: which tool you are using to test the calls other than GET?

Comment: i just use  the rest client Tool (CocoaRestClient). The result is the same with curl

Comment: Did u set the appropriate headers in the restclient

Comment: yes headers are set appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try slashed

```
value = "/{userId}"
```

instead of

```
value = "{userId}"
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help. I just wonder why only Http-GET requests get executed (the findAll and findById methods get executed as expected) and all others not. The findAll (GET) and create(POST) methods share the same url but by the create method just don't get executed

Comment: could you try it:

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody @Valid User user) throws Exception {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.createOrUpdateUser(user));
    }

Comment: Same result. The big problem is that the method don't even get invoked.

Comment: have you copied all the method?

Comment: curl -I http://localhost:8080/user give the expected result as findAll method get invoked.       But  curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{myobjectAsJson}' http://localhost:8080/user   give the 404 Error.

Comment: curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{}' localhost:8080/user 

works for me

Answer (score 0):

it changed your class a bit :

```
RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<String> findAll() {
        return asList("findAll");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String findById(@PathVariable(value = "userId") String userId) {
        return "findById";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{userId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable(value = "userId") String userId) {
        System.out.println("delete");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody @Valid String user) throws Exception {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String update(@RequestBody @Valid String user) {
        return "update";
    }

}
```

and it is the test for it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    protected MediaType contentType = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(),
            Charset.forName("utf8"));

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }




    @Test
    public void testFindAll() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user").contentType(contentType))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindById() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user/1").contentType(contentType))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDelete() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(delete("/user/1").contentType(contentType))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/user").content("new user").contentType(contentType))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(put("/user").content("updated user").contentType(contentType))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

and i passed all tests.
Try to play with signature of method and request mapping. try to run test on your env

Comment: i implemented the unit test for the controller and all works as expected. Thanks for that. The problem seems to be the url access (or client) for other than GET Request. I really don't understand why

Comment: so you can close question

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component    
@RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/user"})
    public class UserController {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public List<User> findAll() {
            LOGGER.info("Finding all User entries");
            return userService.findAllUsers();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public User findById(@PathVariable(value = "userId") String userId) {
            LOGGER.info("Getting the user with the id: " + userId);
            return userService.findUserWithId(userId);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public void delete(@PathVariable(value = "userId") String userId) {
            LOGGER.info("Deleting the user with the id: " + userId);
            userService.deleteUser(userId);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public User create(@RequestBody @Valid User user, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
            LOGGER.info("Creating or Updating a user with the following informations: " + user);
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                throw new Exception("Error in request");
            }
            return userService.createOrUpdateUser(user);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
        public User update(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
            LOGGER.info("Updating the user with the following informations: " + user);
            return userService.createOrUpdateUser(user);
        }

        @ExceptionHandler
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        public void handleUserNotFound(Exception exception) {
            LOGGER.info("An Exception occured in controller " + exception.getMessage());
        }
```

this should solve your problem

Comment: This doesn't help too. The component annotation don't bring much since the controller get found from the application.

Comment: i just not added the @Component, if you see in the RequestMapping for method level you are missing / before the value =, that is the correct way of defining mappings.

Comment: I also added the / sign before any 'value' but same result

Comment: I implemented your controller as-it-is with a dummy UserService and User POJO and it just worked fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

i get it working by setting a new project using STS and copied my old code into the new project. The old code was generated from the command line using Spring-CLI. How and Why this happens is still not clear to me. Thank you very much for the help :)